# Hi, how can I move the logo from the top left corner to the center when I start scrolling. Thanks

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, navbar

I want to know how to move the logo from the top left corner to the center when I start scrolling. Thanks!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and where you are having specific problems. [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Have a onscroll event on the html element you want to scroll;
2. Inside onscroll event handling change the style of logo element to align:center;

something like below(psuedo code):

```
<div onscroll="handleMyScrolling(event)">
 <logo id="logo"></logo>
 
</div>


<script>
 function handleMyScrolling(event){
   document.getElementById('logo').style= // your style to bring the element to 
   center.
 }
</script>
```